# Adding multiple Entries under Order Entry Sales Order Transactions

Tags: sage-erp, intacct

I came to a issue where I want to add multiple entries under a sales order transaction using the Sage Intacct developer API. Is it possible to modify your API to insert multiple entries under Sales order transaction on Sage Intacct?

Answer (score 0):

It already allows you to add multiple lines. See here https://developer.intacct.com/api/order-entry/order-entry-transactions/#create-order-entry-transaction-legacy

There is an array of sotransitem records. If you're doing this via C# there is a legacy method in the SDK called `OrderEntryTransactionCreate` and in there is a Lines list which is a `List<OrderEntryTransactionLineCreate>`. You can add as many as you like.